# Dart: Convert a filtered list to JSON

Tags: json, dart

I'm trying to convert a filtered list to JSON. It works for the original list, but the compiler is giving me an error when I try to do the same against the filtered result: `Uncaught Error: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'WhereIterable<Order>'`.

Example:

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Order {  
  String comment;
  String date;
  String type;  
  
  Order({this.comment, this.date, this.type});
  
  Map toJson() => {    
    'comment': comment,
    'date': date,
    'type': type,
  };
  
   factory Order.fromJson(Map<String, String> map) {
    if (map == null) return null;
  
    return Order(      
      comment: map['comment'],
      date: (map['date']),
      type: map['type'],
    );
  }  
}
const ordersDataMock = ([
    {
      'comment':
          'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
      'date': '03/10/2020',
      'type': 'a',
    },
    {     
      'comment':
          'Nulla eget est placerat, rhoncus libero sit amet, dictum nisl.',
      'date': '03/10/2020',
      'type': 'b',
    },
    {     
      'comment':
          'Mauris ornare fermentum lacus, sit amet dapibus neque.',
      'date': '03/10/2020',
      'type': 'c',
    },
  ]);

void main() {
  List<Order> mock = ordersDataMock.map((item)  => Order.fromJson(item)).toList();
  
  var filtered = mock.where((f) => f.type == 'a');
  
//   print(jsonEncode(mock)); // works!
  
  print(jsonEncode(filtered)); // Uncaught Error: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'WhereIterable<Order>'
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: `filtered` is not a `List` but a `Iterable`. You need to call `toList()` to convert it into a `List`. So: `var filtered = mock.where((f) => f.type == 'a').toList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var filtered = mock.where((f) => f.type == 'a').toList();
```

try this out by calling toList();